# Is it possible to combine "Python FreeOpcUa" with "Mosquito Broker"?

Tags: python, server, broker

Is there any way to combine an OPC-UA Server with a Mosquito Broker? I would like to start a server (OPC UA) which can publish different variables etc. which will be handled by a Broker (Mosquito). Therefore I would like to use the "Python FreeOpcUa" implementation and the official Mosquito Broker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I should be possible if you have control over application layer.

When opc ua layer gives control to read or write a variable node, just before returning control to opc ua layer do all the necessary action to publish data using any broker.

I hope this will help you to solve problem.